# Как обойти баг в MS Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Когда много раз ищешь все ссылки на функцию, переменную, да на всё, что угодно, поиск идёт бесконечно, и при этом при попытке выйти из студии она зависает.

Кто-нибудь обошёл этот баг или знает способ как обойти зависание студии?

Студия больше не обновляется.

Устанавливать другую студию не предлагать.

Comment: а как вы хотите исправить заводской баг, без переустановки другой версии?

Comment: Друзья, оказывается студия давно не обновлялась. Видимо из за того что отключил в настройках обновлений Windows опцию устанавливать обновления для других продуктов MS.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю не устанавливать другую студию, а установить православный `CLion` или в крайнем случае накатить `ReSharper` и искать с помощью него.

Comment: Ну решарпер -- допустим, это вариант, а "другую студию не предлагать" вы видели?

Comment: @AK я написал "Предлагаю не устанавливать другую студию" специально. `CLion` это другая `IDE`, а не другая "студия"

Comment: @AK насколько я понял, устанавливать другую студию = переустановить `Visual Studio`/установить другую версию этой `IDE`